# How can I toggle magic mouse one finger swipe pages gesture via terminal?

Tags: mouse, defaults

How can I toggle magic mouse one finger swipe pages gesture via terminal?

The command `defaults write -g AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool NO` triggers checkbox in System Preferences, but doesn't affect swiping gesture.

Checkbox toggle in System Preferences turns off swipe gesture instantly without need to restart magic mouse. I want to get same functionality from terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one finger swipe gesture on the Magic Mouse is technically a scroll gesture and it can not be disabled, you can investigate the specifics further with my app NSMonitor.

To investigate the correspondence of ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist entries with user interface elements in System Preferences what i do is save a copy of that file as xml, edit something in system preferences, save it again and compare the two.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found out that you have to manipulate `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse`.

I found a config at github from [okine](https://github.com/ohkine/configs/blob/master/config.sh) which had the following code:

```
# Disable full-screen swipe (two-finger swipe) on Magic Mouse
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseTwoFingerHorizSwipeGesture -int 0
```

This should work. Other options are

```
defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
```

Returns

```
{
    MouseButtonDivision = 55;
    MouseButtonMode = TwoButton;
    MouseHorizontalScroll = 0;
    MouseMomentumScroll = 1;
    MouseOneFingerDoubleTapGesture = 0;
    MouseTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture = 3;
    MouseTwoFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 2;
    MouseVerticalScroll = 1;
    UserPreferences = 1;
}
```

Comment: I ask about 'one finger page swap' gesture (first checkbox in preferences). For example back/forward page in browser. Unfortunately `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse` doesn't seem to have this option (correct option is in my original post which doesn't affect actual behaviour too, it just toggles first checkbox in Magic Mouse preferences). I guess there should be another command like "apply changed defaults to current workspace" which should actually do the work.

Comment: I don't have a Magic Mouse but since there are no other options for a Magic Mouse to configure and the equivalent gesture on a trackpad is a two finger swipe I assume that it is the same setting or not possible. Have you at least tried it?

Comment: Sure I tried, didn't work for me.